# How to get all friends irrelevant of presence status

Tags: c#, xmpp, agsxmpp

I'm trying to create a friend's list which is populated when the user logs in but am having issues with loading the offline friends. The `OnPresence` event only seems to be firing for online friends. Am I doing something wrong or is this by design? And if it is by design, is there some workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get your contact list over the OnRosterItem event. This event fires once for every contact.

Consider all contacts as offline by default. For all online contacts you get the OnPresence event.